# Silverlight: TextBlock has no Template property?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, styles

I want to customize the look of a `TextBlock`. (I want a rounded rectangle border around it.)
But I'd like to be able to set its template via the file `app.xaml`.

But I see that TextBlock doesn't have a `Template` property. I'd use Label (which does have a Template property) but I guess Silverlight doesn't support a Label control.

So what can I use to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the solutions I found for this rounding border of text box is available in [Scott Guthrie's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Guthrie) article:

[image]

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-4-using-style-elements-to-better-encapsulate-look-and-feel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The **`Label`** control is not a part of Silverlight 2 rather it is a part of [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528).